# Buttons look different only on ios devices (iphones and ipads). How can this be fixed?

Tags: css, sass

[Sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zZLf.jpg)

[image: Sample 2]

The fact is that on Tablets on mobile phones it looks normal. While only on ios it looks like this with border-radius, long and with the strange look. Is there any way to solve this issue or make the buttons look like on the normal other devices?

Answer (score 0):

Please, add the following line inside the Button class:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```